# I am facing problem of character keys , while I am Logging in and I want to use @ symbol in password its showing " instead

Tags: keyboard, password, keyboard-layout, special-characters

- I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Oracle Virtual Box
- I used my PC QWERTY Keyboard for input & as usual I pressed shift + 2
- They keys are working fine after the login window , example @ is implemented as @ only but my password instead of xyz@ reads xys" as correct

xyz@ -> incorrect
xys" -> correct

- At the time of installation my Keyboard Layout was English (UK), I have changed it to English (US) still the problem persists.

Comment: Once logged in, your user settings/config takes effect, but not all changes made on user accounts impact the system before login. You've indicated Ubuntu 22.04, but are you using default GNOME & `gdm3` as your DM/greeter?  (FYI: I use `sddm` as my DM/greeter, and it has its own setup where I configure settings that impact the greeter/login, my GUI defaults take effect once I've logged in as me)

Answer (score 1):

So you tried to set the password `xyz@` in the installer, but since the English (UK) layout was in use there, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> gave you a password with `"` instead of `@`.

Then I suppose you want to [change your password](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-changepassword.html).